Locating empty <select> fields with a specific class, which are empty
I have multiple select fields on a page, some of them have a required class.
On a click of a button, I would like to add a fieldError class to those ones that remain unselected.
<select class="input-block-level required" id="CellphonePrefix" name="CellphonePrefix" style="width: 85px;">
    <option value="" class="">+Select...</option>
    <option data-countrycode="CY" value="+357"> Cyprus (+357)</option>
</select>

<select class="input-block-level required" id="FaxPrefix" name="FaxPrefix" style="width: 85px;">
    <option value="" class="">+Select...</option>
    <option data-countrycode="CY" value="+357"> Cyprus (+357)</option>
</select>

These are the options I have tried, neither work:
$("#locate").click(function(){
    $("select.required:empty").addClass('fieldError'); 

    $("select.required option:selected[value='']").addClass('fieldError');  <-- this applied the class to option and not select 

})

Thanks

This question is similar to: CSS selector for SELECT html element with nothing selected. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

so using the above answer: $("select.required:has(option[value='']:checked)").addClass('fieldError');  (probably with $('.required.fieldError').removeClass("fieldError"); above it to clear previously error-ed fields)

@NickParsons thank you, this is perfect, and much simpler than creating a loop function to locate these fields.

:empty checks for empty contents of a container element, not an empty value of an input.
Loop over all the selects and use toggleClass() to add or remove the class depending on its value.


$("#locate").click(function() {
  $("select.required").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("fieldError", this.value == "");
  });
})
.fieldError {
  color: red;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="input-block-level required" id="CellphonePrefix" name="CellphonePrefix" style="width: 85px;">
  <option value="" class="">+Select...</option>
  <option data-countrycode="CY" value="+357"> Cyprus (+357)</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="input-block-level required" id="FaxPrefix" name="FaxPrefix" style="width: 85px;">
  <option value="" class="">+Select...</option>
  <option data-countrycode="CY" value="+357"> Cyprus (+357)</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="locate">Locate</button>



